# Drag and drop in QTreeWidget doesn't take children objects

Tags: c++, qt, drag-and-drop

I'm currently facing a problem while using QTreeViewWidget in Qt 5.7.

**Case 1 : Copy/Move Item from widget 2 to widget 1**

Only the dragged item is successfully dropped, without its hierarchy.

**Case 2 : Copy Item from widget 1 to widget 1**

Only the dragged item is successfully dropped, without its hierarchy.

**Case 3 : Move Item from widget 1 to widget 1**

The dragged item is successfully dropped with its hierarchy.

**Question**

What causes this behaviour, and how can it be fixed so the Item's hierarchy is always copied/moved with it ?

**Edit 1 :**
After trying to reproduce it manually with the "insert" function, I think it may be due to a parenting error, where the children of the source hierarchy keep their original parrent, instead of the parent being cloned.

Sample generation :

```
QList<QTreeWidgetItem *> items;

/*Interlock*/
QTreeWidgetItem* interlock;
interlock = new QTreeWidgetItem((QTreeWidget*)0, QStringList("Interlock"));

interlock->addChild(new QTreeWidgetItem((QTreeWidget*)0, QStringList("Bypass")));
interlock->addChild(new QTreeWidgetItem((QTreeWidget*)0, QStringList("Bypass")));

items.append(interlock);

/*Alarme*/
QTreeWidgetItem* alarme;
alarme = new QTreeWidgetItem((QTreeWidget*)0, QStringList("Alarme"));

alarme->addChild(new QTreeWidgetItem((QTreeWidget*)0, QStringList("Criticité")));

//Ajout de 1 Interlocks
alarme->addChild(interlock->clone());

items.append(alarme);

treeWidgetModels->insertTopLevelItems(0, items);
```

Widgets :

```
treeWidget = new QTreeWidget(this);
treeWidget->setColumnCount(2);
treeWidget->setDragEnabled(true);
treeWidget->viewport()->setAcceptDrops(true);
treeWidget->setDropIndicatorShown(true);
treeWidget->setEditTriggers(QAbstractItemView::SelectedClicked);
treeWidget->setDefaultDropAction(Qt::MoveAction);

treeWidgetModels = new QTreeWidget(this);
treeWidgetModels->setColumnCount(2);
treeWidgetModels->setDragEnabled(true);
treeWidgetModels->setDefaultDropAction(Qt::CopyAction);
```

Widget (Top is the destination, Bottom contains the models) :

[image]

Comment: When you want to do more custom things it seems like you need to implement your own drag/drop for this. I am not sure if overriding `mimeData` and `dropMimeData` will do the trick or you need to use the model-view concept of Qt here.

Comment: I saw about reimplementing, however it seems it can handle a hierarchy when moving from a widget ot the same widget. So my question was if I was missing something to copy a full hierarchy from a widget, to the same or another. In the end, I just want to move a parent and its children, nothing more, and Qt looks like it can do it when moving.

Comment: Ah. Hmm I saw your second widget has `CopyAction` as default drop action. Maybe also use move here.  It may be that "copy" only copies the item while with "move" you well move the item with its children

Comment: Already checked that. The bottom widget has `CopyAction` because I need the source to stay inside the widget. Using `MoveAction` only moves the parent, and not its hierarchy, as I said in the Case 1

Comment: @Florent Uguet have you had any luck with this perhaps? Just having the same issue. Dragging parent from 1 view to another ignores hierarchy.

Comment: @Dariusz I haven't been able to fix it, and my company moved to C#, where it worked, so I didn't have to bother about it anymore. You may want to try to post your own question with your own details

Comment: Ah bummer, thanks for update tho! Will try to fix it :- )

Comment: My pleasure ^^ Hope you find a way to get it to work ! You might also want to check how to reimplement the QTreeWidget, as commented above